# Why is the price in the markets endpoint vs the market_chart endpoint different?

Tags: coingecko

Markets endpoint:

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin

`current_price    22105`

Market chart endpoint:

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=7&interval=daily

The last value in the prices array:

`22047.831234213034`

Both called less than a second apart. Both different prices.

Is it not possible to get the most recent current price from the market_chart endpoint? I'm getting rate limited really fast when I make both calls on 1 screen with the free api.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoints have different caching/update frequency.

As stated here in the CoinGecko API [guidebook](https://apiguide.coingecko.com/getting-started/endpoint-demo/common-use-cases#best-endpoint-to-get-the-latest-price),
this seems to be the best & fastest endpoint to get the latest price:
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd